# Entity Framework 4 ExecuteStoreQuery<T> -- unable to results to object-type property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I have an Entity that maps to a table EntityTable and is pretty straight forward, consisting of about 4 or 5 value type properties.  Depending on the database I access, though, the schema is different for one of the properties: in most schemas, it is a `decimal`, in a handful of others, it is a `smallint` (or `Int16` in C#).  Obviously, this trips up EF when it tries to map an `Int16` value into an Entity that expects a `decimal`-typed property.

So my work around was to call ExecuteStoreQuery() on the EF context and have FauxEntity declare the wonky property as an `object` and not explicitly `decimal` or `Int16`.  I could then specifically handle the unboxing of the property manually.

However, this doesn't work!  Instead of an object reference to a boxed `Int16` (or `decimal` value), the property's value is `null`!  This is weird because I can easily declare something like:

```
object intVal = 16;
```

`intVal` will then become an instance of a boxed `int` value.  I can then unbox appropriately.

This is what I'm hoping for with ExecuteStoredProcedure -- it should throw the value into the object property and then I can do a series of unboxing tests to properly unbox the value.  However, the value is never successfully boxed in the `object` property!

**Is this even possible with `ExecuteStoreQuery<T>()`?  Why can't it load a value type into an `object`-typed property?**

BTW, I'm aware I can solve the issue at hand by executing a DataReader against the SQL code and manually casting each result column.  I'm simply wondering why `ExecuteStoreQuery<T>()` isn't behaving as anticipated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [restrictions on `TElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358758.aspx) are in MSDN. Quoting:

> For the previous methods that take a generic result type parameter, the TResult can be a primitive type, an entity type, or any custom type. The type does not have to be defined in the Entity Framework  conceptual model. If the specified type is of a type that is not defined in the conceptual model or is not a primitive type, the following mapping conventions apply.
>
> The type:
>
> - Must not be abstract.
> - Must have a default constructor.
>
> Each property of the type:
>
> - Must have a setter.
> - Must correspond to a primitive type in CSDL.
> - Must correspond to a column name in the resulting DbDataReader (the provider implementation determines whether a column has the same name as the property). If the name of the type's property does not match a field of the DbDataReader, the Entity Framework  materializes the default value of the property if it is defined in the conceptutal model.

Comment: So it looks like that second bullet for the property requirements is what's tripping me up.  `object` sure ain't a primitive type.  Alas.  Thanks Craig for doing the digging in MSDN that I obviously missed!