# Expression of type 'Territory_Manager.HtmlAddressGenerator+Entry' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, sql, linq, frameworks, entity

i realy hope there is someone out there who can help me.

I have the following sql statement (just replaced real column values with '').

```
        string sqlstatement = @"
        SELECT 
            'a' as Street,
            1 as StreetNumber,
            'a' as StreetAddition,
            'a' as Family,
            'a' as FirstNames,
            'a' as VisitedBy
        FROM Person pOuter
        INNER JOIN House h
            ON pOuter.HouseId = h.Id
        INNER JOIN Street s
            ON h.StreetId = s.Id
            AND s.TerritoryID = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Territory WHERE Number=" + selectedEntry.Number + @" AND CityId = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM City WHERE Name ='" + selectedEntry.City.Trim() + @"'))
        GROUP BY 
            pOuter.LastName, 
            pOuter.HouseId
        ORDER By Street ASC, StreetNumber ASC, StreetAddition ASC, Family ASC, FirstNames ASC";
```

and try to execute it and generate into a strong type sequence with following command.

```
database.ExecuteStoreQuery<HtmlAddressGenerator.Entry>(sqlstatement);
```

where database is my entity framework database context (or so).

After getting to this line the debugger throws the error.

The sql statement itself works if executed in SQL Management Studio.
What am i doing wrong? It worked until I've installed win 8. Maybe it has nothing to do with win 8, why does this code works on a XP machine? But that is not the question. I just want to know is there any workaround for that problem or have I overseen sth. very important? What should I do to get the code executed? Please help.

Comment: Does nobody know the answer? Forgot to tell that this is a c# code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is described here [Entity Framework 4 ExecuteStoreQuery<T> -- unable to results to object-type property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344984/entity-framework-4-executestorequeryt-unable-to-results-to-object-type-prop)

The error was that HtmlAddressGenerator.Entry was a struct and has no default constrcutor. So changing the struct into a class and adding a default constructor has solved my problem.